# Отладка multiprocessing в Python

Tags: python, отладка, процесс

Иногда один из процессов подвисает на блокировке очереди и все стопорится пока его не убьешь.

Класс дает общий интерфейс для работы с архивами :

```
class Arch():
    def __init__( self, name, path = None ):
        from os import path
        self.name = name
        if path == None:
            self.path = path.dirname( __file__ )
        else:
            self.path = path
    def name_list( self ):
        for item in self.arch_desc.infolist():
            if not item.filename.endswith('/'):
                yield item.filename
        #return self.arch_desc.namelist()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.arch_desc.name
    def extract( self, file_name ):
           self.arch_desc.extract( file_name )
class ZipArch( Arch ):
    def __init__( self, name, path = None ):
        Arch.__init__( self, name , path )
        self.open()
    def open( self ):
        from zipfile import ZipFile
        self.arch_desc = ZipFile( self.name, 'r' )
    def __str__( self ):
        return self.arch_desc.filename
class RarArch( Arch ):
    def __init__( self, name, path = None ):
        Arch.__init__( self, name , path )
        self.open()
    def open( self ):
        from rarfile import RarFile
        self.arch_desc = RarFile( self.name, 'r' )
    def name_list( self ):
        for item in self.arch_desc.infolist():
            if not item.isdir():
                yield item.filename
class TarArch( Arch ):
    def __init__( self, name, path = None ):
        Arch.__init__( self, name , path )
        self.open()
    def open( self ):
        import tarfile
        if self.name[-7:] == '.tar.gz' : readstate = 'r:gz'
        elif self.name[-8:] == '.tar.bz2' :  readstate = 'r:bz2'
        else : readstate = 'r:tar'
        self.arch_desc = tarfile.open( self.name , readstate )
    def name_list( self ):
        return [ i.name for i in self.arch_desc.getmembers() if not i.isdir() ]
```

Основной код :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Process
import logging as Log
Log.basicConfig( level = Log.DEBUG,format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(processName)12s - %(message)s' )
class ExedProc( Process ):
    def __init__( self, queue, arch):
        Process.__init__( self )
        self.queue = queue
        self.arch = arch
        self.log = Log.getLogger('SubProc')
    def run( self ):
        import os
        while not self.queue.empty():
            file = self.queue.get( )
            self.arch.extract( file )
            self.log.info('Извлекается файл'+'  -  [' + file + ']')
        os._exit(0)
class Exed():
    def __init__( self, name, path = None, proc = None):
        from multiprocessing import Queue, cpu_count
        from executor import TarArch, RarArch, ZipArch
        #Логирование 
        self.log = Log.getLogger('main')
        self.log.info('Запуск распаковки %s' % (name) )
        #Тип архива
        if name[-8:] == '.tar.bz2' or name[-4:] == '.tar' or name[-7:] == '.tar.gz':
            self.arch = TarArch( name )
        elif name[-4:] == '.zip':
            self.arch =ZipArch( name )
        elif name[-4:] == '.rar':
            self.arch = RarArch( name )
        self.log.info('Тип архива : %s' % self.arch.__class__.__name__.__str__() )
        #Очередь
        self.queue = Queue()
        for item in self.arch.name_list():
            self.queue.put( item )
        #Лист процессов
        if proc == None:
            self.proc = cpu_count()
        else:
            self.proc = proc
        #self.proc = 1
        self.proc_list = [ ExedProc( self.queue, self.arch ) for item in range( self.proc )]
    def stop( self ):
        self.runing = False
        for item in self.proc_list:
            item.terminate()
    def start( self):
        self.runing = True
        for item in self.proc_list:
            item.start()
            print(item)
#Проверят жив ли хотя бы один из процессов
def is_alive( list ):
    for i in list:
        if i.is_alive():return True
    return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, sys, time
    test = Exed( os.path.dirname( __file__ ) + sys.argv[1] )
    test.start()
    while is_alive( test.proc_list ):
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            test.stop()
            test.log.warn( 'Остановлено' )
```

В общем вопрос в том как отлаживать multiprocessing приложения , потому как отладчики и ни breackpoint ни pdb , ни strace мне не помогают.

Comment: логи. и ещё раз логи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Искал вот это, может кому пригодится:

```
import multiprocessing, logging
logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)
```